# "Will Jay have left work already?": the future perfect

Tags: meaning, grammar, future-perfect

It's said that the future perfect (*will* + *have* + past participle) is used to say that something will be completed by a particular time, as in

> 1. By next summer I'**ll have finished my degree.**

But in the example

> 2. It's 5.30. **Will** Jay **have left** work already?

it seems to me that the second sentence could be replaced by

> 3. Has Jay left work already?

which is of the present perfect tense, without any significant change in meaning.

Please let me know if I'm correct.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence 3 is a straightforward request for information, and it assumes the hearer knows or will find out the answer. The answer is expected to be authoritative. Sentence 2 is expressed as a request for a prediction, and it does not assume the hearer knows the answer. An opinion, not an authoritative answer, is expected as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct.

A possible nuance is

> Has Jay left work already?

is a normal unemphasized question, whereas

> Will Jay have left work already?

might have the feeling

> **Will** Jay **have left** work already?
>   *I can't believe, has Jay left work already?*